# The same activity performed by two different actors in a swim lane

Tags: uml, bpmn

I want to have the same task to be performed by two different actors in the swim lane. This is not a shared activity however could be performed by any of the 2 actors.

[image]

Currently I am dividing it into 1.0a and 1.0b but its creating problems as each one has separate sub process.

Please assist.

Comment: Maybe if you illustrate your current state of work someone can help. But that way I voted to close your question as unclear.

Comment: @Aks: I quickly sketched [https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFl4I.png] my understanding of what you do *not* want to have, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Your question is still very unclear. What  are "1.0a" and "1.0b"? What do you mean with your sentence that both actors have a "separate sub process"?

Answer (score 1):

The question of how to model shared tasks is discussed in the [BPMN 2.0 Handbook Second Edition](https://books.google.de/books?id=9U3DO5PoTDQC&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=bpmn%20%22shared%20activity%22&source=bl&ots=TV0uC_np7-&sig=ACfU3U2CeWtFndblBev1froHOJlmPU5qsg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwja5euh5InkAhX_wAIHHVhdBjYQ6AEwA3oECAkQAQ) in the article "Collaborative Activities inside Pools" by Michele Chinosi on page 150.